# How to group similar rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
Date        ConfigID    ItemID    ClientName    Metric1    Metric2
====        ========    ======    ==========    =======    =======
2017-01-01  1           1         A             2.0        2.0
2017-01-01  3           1         A             2.0        2.0
2017-01-01  4           2         B             5.0        5.0
2017-01-02  4           3         A             6.0        6.0
2017-01-01  2           1         A             2.0        2.0
....
(20 million rows here)
```

I wanted to detect the duplicates here based on `Date`, `ItemID`, `ClientName`, `Metric1` and `Metric2`, so I wrote:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable ([Date] date,
                      ConfigID int,
                      ItemID int,
                      ClientName char(1),
                      Metric1 decimal(3,1),
                      Metric2 decimal(3,1));
INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES ('2017-01-01',1,1,'A',2.0,2.0),
       ('2017-01-01',3,1,'A',2.0,2.0),
       ('2017-01-01',4,2,'B',5.0,5.0),
       ('2017-01-02',4,3,'A',6.0,6.0),
       ('2017-01-01',2,1,'A',2.0,2.0);    

WITH Dupes          
AS (            
    SELECT *        
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (    
            PARTITION BY 
                [Date]
               ,[ItemID]
               ,[ClientName]
               ,[Metric1]
               ,[Metric2]
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC
    ) AS RowNum 
    FROM myTable)

SELECT *
FROM Dupes
```

But that returns something like this:

```
Date        ConfigID    ItemID    ClientName    Metric1    Metric2    RowNum
====        ========    ======    ==========    =======    =======    ======
2017-01-01  1           1         A             2.0        2.0        1
2017-01-01  3           1         A             2.0        2.0        2
2017-01-01  4           2         B             5.0        5.0        1
2017-01-02  4           3         A             6.0        6.0        1
2017-01-01  2           1         A             2.0        2.0        3
....
(20 million rows here)
```

I would like to group the similar items based on the `PARTITION BY` clause. In other words, I'd like to see something like this (I don't really need `RowNum`):

```
Date        ConfigID    ItemID    ClientName    Metric1    Metric2    RowNum
====        ========    ======    ==========    =======    =======    ======
2017-01-01  1           1         A             2.0        2.0        1
2017-01-01  3           1         A             2.0        2.0        2
2017-01-01  2           1         A             2.0        2.0        3
2017-01-01  4           2         B             5.0        5.0        1
2017-01-02  4           3         A             6.0        6.0        1
....
(20 million rows here)
```

What SQL query would help me group the duplicate/similar rows in a table? Thank you in advanced for suggestions and answers!

Comment: What do you mean by "group" them? Do you want to not return them in your dataset? Aggragate them? Something else?

Comment: @Larnu, I meant I want to review them manually to see where things are different (e.g., I can see how many different ConfigID are having the same values in other columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER could help?

```
;           
WITH Dupes          
AS (            
    SELECT *        
        ,DENSE_RANK ( )
        OVER (    
            ORDER BY
                [Date]
               ,[ItemID]
               ,[ClientName]
               ,[Metric1]
               ,[Metric2]           
             DESC
    ) AS GroupID 
    FROM myTable)

SELECT *
FROM Dupes
```

here the solution proposed:

```
;           
WITH D1          
AS (            
    SELECT *        
        ,DENSE_RANK ( )
        OVER (    
            ORDER BY
                [Date]
               ,[ItemID]
               ,[ClientName]
               ,[Metric1]
               ,[Metric2]           
             DESC
    ) AS GroupID 
    FROM myTable)
, Dupes AS (
    SELECT *
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID) AS GroupItemsCount
    FROM D1
)
SELECT *
FROM Dupes
WHERE GroupItemsCount <> 1
```

but a better way could be

```
;           
WITH Dupes          
AS (            
    SELECT *        
        ,COUNT(*)
        OVER (    
            partition BY
                [Date]
               ,[ItemID]
               ,[ClientName]
               ,[Metric1]
               ,[Metric2]           
    ) AS GroupItemsCount
    FROM myTable)

SELECT *
FROM Dupes
WHERE GroupItemsCount > 1
```

Comment: Yes! `DENSE_RANK` is close to what I wanted. But how would one extract the data with **more than one row** in a given rank from the query above? For example, say three rows have rank of '1', the rest of the rows have a unique rank assigned to them (2...n). Then I'd like to only extract/review the one with rank '1'. What additional query would help here? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not behind my PC but I suggest you to try COUNT() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID) as GroupItemsCount in another CTE and filter GroupItemsCount > 1

Comment: YES!! `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY....)` and filtering based on `count > 1` and ordering by all criteria inside `PARTITION BY` clause  works!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

just give an order by in the select

```
;           
WITH Dupes          
AS (            
    SELECT *        
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (    
            PARTITION BY 
                [Date]
               ,[ItemID]
               ,[ClientName]
               ,[Metric1]
               ,[Metric2]
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC
    ) AS RowNum 
    FROM myTable)

SELECT *
FROM Dupes
order by [Date]
               ,[ItemID]
               ,[ClientName]
               ,[Metric1]
               ,[Metric2],
RowNum
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need `order by`.  And the CTE is not necessary:

```
. . .
SELECT *
FROM Dupes
ORDER BY [Date], [ItemID], [ClientName], [Metric1], [Metric2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Luca's suggestion in the comment, using `COUNT(*) PARTITION BY(...)` seems to work:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable ([Date] date,
                      ConfigID int,
                      ItemID int,
                      ClientName char(1),
                      Metric1 decimal(3,1),
                      Metric2 decimal(3,1));
INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES ('2017-01-01',1,1,'A',2.0,2.0),
       ('2017-01-01',3,1,'A',2.0,2.0),
       ('2017-01-01',4,2,'B',5.0,5.0),
       ('2017-01-02',4,3,'A',6.0,6.0),
       ('2017-01-01',2,1,'A',2.0,2.0);    

WITH Dupes          
AS (            
    SELECT *        
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (    
            PARTITION BY 
                [Date]
               ,[ItemID]
               ,[ClientName]
               ,[Metric1]
               ,[Metric2]
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC
    ) AS DupeCount 
    FROM myTable)

SELECT *
FROM Dupes
WHERE DupeCount > 1
```

Comment: Agreed, @Forty3. It works. Thank you for writing up the answer. I found that adding `ORDER BY [Date] ,[ItemID],[ClientName],[Metric1],[Metric2]` after `WHERE DupeCount >1` to help me easily review dupes. :)